# Don't ask me to approve closure of questions I edited

Tags: feature-request, edits, vote-to-close

The closure review queue can include questions I edited but chose not to vote to closure. This seems pointless: if I edited the question I've read it; if I've edited it but not already voted to close it, I must have already decided the question is worth keeping.

Comment: So, skip? That should do the trick?

Comment: Seems like there's a range of possibilities here, and I don't know which ones are implemented. You probably shouldn't ask me to close anything I've answered or commented on, either -- if I wanted to close it, I would have voted while I was there the first time.

Answer (score 9):

> if I edited the question I've read it; if I've edited it but not already voted to close it, I must have already decided the question is worth keeping.

While that's certainly plausible, some folks *do* edit questions they think should be closed, without then voting to close. Possible reasons:

- They want to give the author a bit of time to add some missing information before voting.
- Their edit fixed whatever problems were affecting the question, but then the author edited them back in / rolled back the fixes.
- The question was already closed when they edited, and was later re-opened.
- They don't want their name to appear first in the list of close-voters for some reason.
- They lacked the reputation to vote to close when they made the edit.
- Their computer died immediately after their edit was submitted, and they lost track of the question due to the distraction.
- As above, but involving the temporary death of the editor rather than the computer.
- They *meant* to click "close" but instead clicked "edit" and were too lazy to go back so made some minor edit instead.
- They were looking for an "on hold" button but couldn't find one, so gave up.

[As Manishearth notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187769/dont-ask-me-to-approve-closure-of-questions-i-edited/187772#187772), you can still click "Leave Open". Heck, you can even edit it *again* if you see something you missed.

Answer (score 3):

If you've decided the question is worth keeping, then give it a "Leave Open" vote.

Also, it won't always be the case that you edited it but "felt it was worth keeping open". If you were making a formatting edit, you may not have realized the other issues in the first place.